# No Touch with ThreeJS OrbitControls using WebGL on IOS Devices with Ludei / Cocoon JS

Tags: ios, three.js, mobile-safari, webgl, cocoonjs

Following problem:

I'm using the OrbitControls of ThreeJS plugin to rotate around a sphere. This works fine as long as i use the CanvasRenderer. As soon as i switch to the WebGLRenderer the touch controls stop working on iOS Devices through the launcher App.

Does anyone have the same problems or an idea how to solve it? I spend ours searching the web but found nothing related.

The Launcher Log keeps repeating the Same Error:

```
JavaScript Exception ( Tag: 'requestAnimationFrame'): texImage2D IllegalStateException: Error     
reading the '204 bytes' block of the given 
'private/var/mobile/Applications/9DC0353A-C421-4FC4-9731-F1867B377523/tmp/game/' file path. at  
static SPData com::ideateca::core::io::AbstractFileSystem::loadFile(const string &):69
```

Does anybody have an idea what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the OrbitControls. I switched to TrackballControls and it works!